# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0:

Tags: android, xml, binary, line

I am new in android studio and I would like a little help, I'm sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language.

When wanting to enter an activity in my application. This is over, here is the code:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kefagothstudios.cleaner/com.kefagoth.cleaner.ui.RubbishCleanActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.ferdi.cleaner.widget.textcounter.CounterView
```

**this is the activity that fails**

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:counter="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
        android:background="@color/yellow_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <com.ferdi.cleaner.widget.textcounter.CounterView
                android:id="@+id/textCounter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="\ 250"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="52.0sp"
                counter:autoStart="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sufix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_right"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textCounter"
                android:text="KB"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_middle" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sufix"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_right"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textCounter"
                android:text="Freeable"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_middle" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="?android:windowBackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <fr.castorflex.android.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_width="50.0dip"
            android:layout_height="50.0dip"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            counter:cpb_colors="@array/gplus_colors" />

        <com.ferdi.cleaner.views.RotateLoading
            android:id="@+id/rotate_loading"
            android:layout_width="88.0dip"
            android:layout_height="88.0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progressBarText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4.0dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/scanning"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/memory_ads_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="4.0dip"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/listview_layout_animation"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="12.0dip"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/empty_cache"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/memory_ads_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_height"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adsView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_lin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_normal_green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Clean Junk"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroud_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="192.0dip"
            android:layout_height="192.0dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <com.ferdi.cleaner.views.HoloCircularProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/clean_done_holoCircularProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    app1:marker_progress="0.0"
                    app1:marker_visible="false"
                    app1:progress="1"
                    app1:progress_background_color="@color/circle_progress_background"
                    app1:progress_color="@color/circle_progress"
                    app1:stroke_width="6.0dip" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/clean_done_iv_bg"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16.0dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_floating_bg"
                    android:rotation="-30.0"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/clean_done_iv_done"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="40.0dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cleaning"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/clean_up_rocket"
                    android:layout_width="112.0dip"
                    android:layout_height="112.0dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clean_up_done_tv_notice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="16.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="32.0dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/boost_notice"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12.0sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/clean_up_done_icon_container"
            android:layout_width="144.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="32.0dip">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/clean_up_tv_done"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48.0dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="32.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/button_done_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="64.0dip"
                android:paddingBottom="8.0dip"
                android:paddingLeft="32.0dip"
                android:paddingRight="32.0dip"
                android:paddingTop="8.0dip"
                android:text="DONE"
                android:textColor="@color/phoneboost_text_top_color_white_blue"
                android:textSize="16.0sp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my application stops and I do not understand why, I would like an idea of why it stops, in advance thank you very much

Comment: com.ferdi.cleaner.widget.textcounter.CounterView    this view is not inflate

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I definitely see is 'Android won't be able to identify app1 namespace'.

```
<com.ferdi.cleaner.views.HoloCircularProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/clean_done_holoCircularProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    app1:marker_progress="0.0"
                    app1:marker_visible="false"
                    app1:progress="1" app1:progress_background_color="@color/circle_progress_background"
                    app1:progress_color="@color/circle_progress"
                    app1:stroke_width="6.0dip" />
```

But since the inflateException mentions the issue with `com.ferdi.cleaner.widget.textcounter.CounterView` as well, there seems to be another issue with the attribute definition of the counter view. Please verify the same.